# SQL Management Studio só se conecta remotamente sem a instância

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, microsoft, ssms

Ao tentar realizar uma conexão com um primeiro SQL remoto, percebi que o meu Management Studio não conseguia se conectar utilizando a instância, como a seguir:

[image: tentativa de conexão com a instância]

Depois dessa tentativa, removi a instância, e como este servidor só possui um SQL, ele pegou o sistema default, e logou normalmente sem a instância:

[image: conexão realizada com sucesso.]

Agora meu problema, é que estou tentando me conectar a um banco de dados que possui várias instâncias, e meu SQL gera o seguinte erro:

[image: teste com o outro servidor, com instancia]

Supondo que eu teste sem a instância, gera um erro de login, pois ele nao encontra meu usuário e senha no banco de dados default.

Eu já mudei a versão do meu Management Studio para 2014 (estava usando 2017)
Já formatei meu computador na última noite
Instalei novamente o Management Studio 2017

E até o momento, não obtive sucesso algum.
Alguém já passou pelo mesmo problema, ou teria alguma ideia de solução?

Comment: Experimente da seguinte forma: **192.99.140.108\MSSQLSERVER2012:1433**, colocando a porta no fim.

Comment: João, eu obtive um erro de connection string invalida ao tentar inserir a porta do jeito que mencionou